# How do I change the bootstrap website font to futura book?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

Need to change font thruout bootstrap/css based website to Futura Book.

I had this at the top of each HTML page in the head:

Customer wants to change to Futura Book:

I tried this in the head of each HTML page but it doesn't work...

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family="FuturaBT Book", Arial, sans-serif:400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have also edited the CSS with the following, but still no luck.

/* font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; (old font)
    font-family: 'FuturaBT Book', Arial, sans-serif;

Am not getting error messages, but the Futura Book font isn't appearing.

Comment: did you pay for it?  because it Available from these external foundries

Comment: link return 404 status

Comment: I did pay for it.  But need to know how to upload and run from that.  I assume that would be the best/fastest solution.

Answer (score 3):

this is one of the solutions. you can try with different link instead of use googleapis

```css
.FuturaFont{
   font-family:"Futura Book";
}
```

```html
<link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/b46bb1fc76216f5cd90457d0451dbee4?family=Futura+Book" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 

<p class="FuturaFont">Hello</p>
```